# Assign children to object in casperjs

Tags: javascript, object, casperjs, assign

I am trying to assign to nested object (in `casperjs`):

```
    var yearz = [];
    var yearz2 = $('#form_model optgroup');
    yearz2.each(function() {
        var theyear = $(this).attr('label');        
        var theobj = {
            Year: theyear,
            Thing: [{}]
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).children().length; i++){
            theobj["Thing"].push({Name: $(this).children()[i].attr("value")});
        }

        yearz.push(theobj);
    });
```

`this.echo(yearz)` returns`null`
Can you see the problem?

Best Regards

`EDIT`

```
var yearz = [];
var yearz2 = $('#form_model optgroup');
yearz2.each(function() {
    var theyear = $(this).attr('label');
    var lengthch = $(this).children().length; 
    var thisch = $(this).children();      
    var theobj = [];
    var alls = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthch; i++){
        alls.push(thisch.attr("value"));
    }

    theobj = {
        Year: theyear.trim(),
        Thing: alls
    };

    yearz.push(theobj);
});
```

This pushes same element in `alls` array. But there are two of them. How can i push both of them, not the same twice?

This does not work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lengthch; i++){
    alls.push(thisch[i].attr("value")); //Note [i] here.
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "does not work"

Comment: @Satpal does not work. The returned object is `null`

Comment: What returned object? You have no return statement in that code.

Comment: @user1665355 is the console error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)[i].attr is not a function(…)`?

Comment: @AlexSzabó Object is `null`

Comment: `Thing: [{}]` why the empty object?

Comment: @epascarello Please see edit.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < lengthch; i++){
        alls.push(thisch[i].attr("value"));
    }

Comment: @codemonkey65 No, see accepted answer :)

Comment: This is a pretty terrible title. Can you come up with a better one that is more specific to your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alls.push(thisch[i].attr("value")); //Note [i] here.
```

That does not work because [] returns a DOM, not a jQuery object and DOM does not have .attr()

so it should be

```
thisch.eq(i).val()
```

or

```
thisch[i].value
```

You can also just use each() or map() instead of the for loop.

```
var values = thisch.map( function() { return this.value; } ).get();
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot! Did not know that. So `[]` returns DOM?

Answer (score -2):

A shot in the dark, because context is unknown, but try:

```
var yearz = [];
var yearz2 = $('#form_model optgroup');
yearz2.each(function(i, item) {
    var theyear = $(item).attr('label');        
    var theobj = {
        Year: theyear,
        Thing: [{}]
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < $(item).children().length; i++){
        theobj["Thing"].push({Name: $(item).children()[i].attr("value")});
    }

    yearz.push(theobj);
});
```

Comment: No object is still `null`

Comment: What does a yearz2.length report after you have assigned it? Add an alert after the assignment to check?